# Roleplaying online without having to post in public

Tags: online-roleplaying, play-by-post, tool-recommendation

I've recently tried [Hero Central](http://www.herocentral.net/home.htm) for running a Hero System campaign. We have two problems with Hero Central though: it requires posting in English (our group is German-speaking), and campaigns are can be read by the public.

Are there any similar online hosted tools—that offer forums, and optionally additional chats for separating things like setting information and actual play—that don't have an English-only rule and allow campaigns to be made private?

I'm looking specifically for a hosted option, as I'd prefer to not deal with downloading clients or running a server.

Comment: Related: [What online chat or chat-like resource will work for my closed game?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/what-online-chat-or-chat-like-resource-will-work-for-my-closed-game/34862#34862)

Comment: Related: [What software is available for virtual table tops?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/what-software-is-available-for-virtual-table-tops)

Comment: My player will kill me if he has to pay for something^^'. Although from what I see most aside from hero central and roll20 have downloads as a necessity?

Comment: @ThomasE. Those links aren't really exact answers, since they were specifically looking for real-time chat (the former) and virtual tabletops (the latter). (If they *did* answer this question, this would be closed as a duplicate. :) So they are related, but not necessarily helpful to everyone with your same question. Let's see what answers this question gets, since I imagine there are other sites that aren't chat/VTTs that could satisfy your request and wouldn't show up on those questions.

Comment: ^^ It could have been though. As example roll20 has a few features that come quite close to what I want but some things like me having to "run" the campaign are conterproductive enough that it doesn't satisfy my needs there sadly.

Answer (score 4):

[Rpol.net](http://rpol.net/) is a great tool for this purpose. Not only are all posts made in the name of your character rather than your account name, but all posts are only visible to the people the GM allows. Except of course for moderators and the site owners. It is also free.

Comment: It's worth noting that ALL posts are visible to the site's moderators, including PMs.

Comment: are moderators hired stuff or normal ppl there? (if hired staff it is completely clear they have access to everything, else interesting design choice)

Comment: @ThomasE. The site is free, I'm not sure if there is any hired staff. But at the same time, there are very few moderators.

Answer (score 4):

[Roll20](http://roll20.net) has private forums for each campaign, and no site policy on the language you use there. While Roll20 has subscriptions (US$5-10 per month or US$50-100 per year), they are not required to play – rather, the subscriptions add convenience features.

I have seen both German and Russian language games looking for players in Roll20's LFG forum, and I'm certain there are other non-English languages being used as well.

I'm a little unclear from the comments whether you're looking to run a play-by-post game or a realtime game, but both options are available to you on Roll20 between the campaign forum and the virtual tabletop. The forum software does not support dice rolls in posts, however the tabletop keeps a history which you could use to reference rolls.

Comment: It is a mix between chat and play by post.  you mentioned forums there? where are those? (never seen them in iroll20)

Comment: If you create or join a campaign, you can go to the campaign details page. Near the top are several links, including "Discussion Forum". (Recent/stickied topics will also appear on the details page.)

Comment: tnx found it. that button is so......its so easily overlooked that I didnt see it a whole year while using roll20 for chat games^^  tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can try Obsidian Portal. Only the GM has to pay, but you can use a forum, a wiki, and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: Even the GM doesn't have to pay, but you get a lot less functionality if you don't.  I know the wiki is available for free - are the forums?

Comment: No, the forums are not, unfortunately! That's why I mentioned paying =)

Comment: how is it in regards to language support there? can you play also in dutch or german,...?  Also on that is it possible to say that wiki or forum or parts of are private to only th eplaying players can see those?

Comment: Also does it allow for play by post also? (did see a wiki when looking through but not much that indicated play by post is possible)

Comment: You can play in any language. You can set your entire campaing private, so only people you invite can see stuff. There is a wiki and a forum for each of your campaings.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Google Wave until they closed it down, the project is now managed by Apache foundation. I would suggest trying IRC as a persistent chat for RP; or trying out waveinabox.net...

APACHE WAVE:

http://waveinabox.net/auth/signin?r=/

IRC:

See: https://blog.freenode.net/2008/04/registering-a-channel-on-freenode/

You can use a plugin IRC client for Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/circ/bebigdkelppomhhjaaianniiifjbgocn

Or similar for Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chatzilla/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/freenode-irc-client/

Comment: There is a hosted instance of Wave run by Rizzoma. My impression is that they mostly target a business market, but it is still available to anyone who wants to use it.

Comment: tested rizzoma out a bit. what is a bit problematic there and also with other variants (except obsidian) is that you can't structure them very good.